# Include php and html inside an echo in PHP

Tags: php

Simple php really, just can't get it for some reason...

```
<?php
$myvalue = 'yes'
if ( $myvalue == 'yes' ) {
    echo 'This is some test content, within which is some more php bits 
    <?php echo 'Test'; ?> and an if statement 
    <?php if ( $anothervalue = "test" ) { echo 'Print this'; } else 
    { echo 'Print that' ; } ?>
    And then some more content
    <br />
    Test
    ?>

} else {
    echo 'The value didnt match';
}
?>
```

I need to include the php inside the echo, how can i do this?

Comment: use concatenation.
echo 'the value didnt match : '.$myvalue ;

Comment: Use `"text text <?php echo 'I am php'; ?>"` or escape the string `'text text <?php echo \'I am php\'; ?>'`. If you want to actually print php code. Else `"text".$var."text".func()."text"`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't. `echo` is just for outputting.

Refactor instead.

```
<?php
  $myvalue = 'yes'
  if ( $myvalue == 'yes' ) {
?>
This is some test content, within which is some more php bits <?php echo 'Test'; ?> and an if statement 
<?php 
    if ( $anothervalue = "test" ) { 
      echo 'Print this'; 
    } else {
      echo 'Print that' ; 
    } 
?>
And then some more content
<br />
Test
<?php
} else {
    echo 'The value didnt match';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function dosomething($anothervalue){
if ( $anothervalue = "test" ) {
return 'Print this'; } 
else { return 'Print that' ; } 
}


$myvalue = 'yes'
if ( $myvalue == 'yes' ) {
echo 'This is some test content, within which is some more php bits'.dosomething('anothervalue'); ?>
And then some more content


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create a function first:

```
<?php

function dosomething($anothervalue){
if ( $anothervalue = "test" ) {
return 'Print this'; } 
else { return 'Print that' ; } 
}
```

then include it in your statement/text;

```
$myvalue = 'yes'
    if ( $myvalue == 'yes' ) {
    echo 'This is some test content, within which is some more php bits'.dosomething('anothervalue'); ?>
    And then some more content


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate strings bits with the `.` operator:

```
echo 'This is some test content' . ' chained to other stuff' . someFunction() . 'and some other stuff' . $someVariable . ', right?';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
    $myvalue = 'yes';
    if ( $anothervalue == "test" ) { $test = 'Print this'; } else { $test = 'Print that' ; }
    if ( $myvalue == 'yes' ) {
        echo "This is some test content, within which is some more php bits $test
        <br />
        Test";
    }
    else
    {
         echo 'The value didnt match';
    }
?>
```

Comment: No need to concatenate strings. If you use " instead of ' as your string identifier, you can just echo the variable right in the string... $test = "world"; echo "Hello $test";

Answer (score 0):

You can certain express conditional text in the context of an `echo`.  You can use string concatenation (using commas or dots) with inline conditional syntax ([ternary operators](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)) so that you don't have to bounce in and out of `<?php` nor would you need to write multiple echos.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bueeL))

```
$myvalue = 'yes';
$anothervalue = 'test';
if ($myvalue == 'yes') {
    echo 'This is some test content, within which is some more php bits Test ' , ($anothervalue == 'test' ? 'Print this' : 'Print that') , ' And then some more content<br />Test';
} else {
    echo 'The value didnt match';
}
```

Output:

```
This is some test content, within which is some more php bits Test Print this And then some more content<br />Test
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try concatenation like

```
echo "<img src='".$url."' />";
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this but I suggest you go to w3schools and learn up on the basics before continuing.

```
<?php
  $myvalue = 'yes';
  if ( $myvalue == 'yes' ) {
     echo 'This is some test content, within which is some more php bits Test and an if statement';
  if ( $anothervalue = "test" ) { 
      echo 'Print this'; 
  } 
  else { 
      echo 'Print that'; 
  }
?>
And then some more content
<br />
Test
<?php
   }
   else
   {
      echo 'The value didnt match';
   }
?>
```